# Configure the delay before window showing command completions is shown

Tags: spacemacs, completion

When I start entering a command and pause, this helpful window pops up at the bottom:

[image]

When I don't pause, it doesn't show up.

But sometimes, it takes more time to complete a command that I know, e.g. if it requires me to access modifier keys like shift or control.

In those cases, this window briefly flashes and disappears, often also freezing up the editor for about half a second or so.

How can I increase this pause time so I'm only shown the command completions if the pause is longer than, say 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for showing command completions?  That looks a like `which-key`.  If that's the case, I think you should modify `which-key-idle-delay`:

```
Delay (in seconds) for which-key buffer to popup. This
 variable should be set before activating which-key-mode.

A value of zero might lead to issues, so a non-zero value is
recommended
(see https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key/issues/134).
```

You may need to disable and re-enable `which-key-mode` to see the change take effect.

Comment: I haven't installed anything myself, it's whatever that comes with spacemacs. I'll verify if I indeed am using `which-key`.